# How to generate a bump map from two slightly different meshes?

Tags: bump

Suppose that there is a mesh A.

After very slightly and subtly sculpting it (changing some vertices' positions), it becomes mesh B.

Now I want to generate a bump map which represents mild differences of surface height between those two meshes.

I specifically need a bump map, not a normal map.
And I do know that a bump map on an object does not change vertices' actual positions.

How should I do?